# _CrtlIsValidHeapPointer error during destruction

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks, char, destructor

I'm, getting a `_CrtlIsValidHeapPointer(block)` error when my display object `t_display` is being deconstructed. This occurs after the while loop in Animation.cpp for getting user input and making multiple displays.

I know this is because I allocate memory for `char * p_name`, and store that pointer in the object, but I'm not sure how to get around it. I have to use a char * for the display object name, so that must mean I have to allocate memory for it.

I think there could be one of two issues.
1) I'm allocating memory wrong for a char *, or copying the string incorrectly
2) I wrote the destructor wrong

In both cases I'm unsure how to fix this error i'm getting and hoping you can point me in the right direction.

### Animation.cpp

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std;

#include "Display.h"
#include "Frame.h"
#include "Animation.h"


void Animation::InsertFrame() {

    int numDisplays; //for user input of display number
    vector <Display>v; //vector for containing display objects
    int p_x; //will contain user input for pixel_x
    int p_y; //will contain user input for pixel_y
    int p_duration; //will contain user input for duration
    char * p_name; //temp string to contain user input for name

   //will contain p_name to be passed to display constructor
    string frameName; //contains user input for the frame name
    int q = 0; //used to count the diplay #

    //begin reading user input
    cout << "Insert a Frame in the Animation\nPlease enter the Frame filename: " ;
    cin >> frameName;
    cout << "Entering the Frame Displays (the sets of dimensions and durations) " << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of Displays: " ;
    cin >> numDisplays;
    string d_name;

    //display creation loop for # of displays entered
    while (numDisplays > 0) {
        //char * name=nullptr;
        cout << "Please enter pixel x for Display #"<<q<<" pixel_x:";
        cin >> p_x;
        cout << "Please enter pixel y for Display #"<<q<<" pixel_y:" ;
        cin >> p_y;
        cout << "Please enter the duration sec for this Display: " ;
        cin >> p_duration;
        cout << "Please enter the name for this Display: " ;
        //cin >> p_name;
        cin >> d_name;
        //p_name = new char[strlen(name)];
        p_name = new char[d_name.length() + 1]; //allocate for the size of the name entered
        strcpy(p_name, d_name.c_str()); //copy string to char []
        Display t_display =  Display(p_x, p_y, p_duration, p_name); //make a new display with the user input values
        v.push_back(t_display); //pushing onto the vector
        numDisplays--;
        q++;

    }
```

### Display.h

```
// Display.h
#pragma once

class Display
{
    int pixel_x;
    int pixel_y;
    int duration;
    char* name;
public:
    Display(int x, int y, int duration, char* name);
    Display(const Display&);
    ~Display();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Display&);
};
```

---

### Display.cpp

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std;
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display(int x, int y, int d, char* n):pixel_x(x), pixel_y(y), duration(d), name(n) {
}
Display::Display(const Display& p) {
    //copy values from p
    pixel_x = p.pixel_x;
    pixel_y = p.pixel_y;
    duration = p.duration;
    name = p.name;

}
Display::~Display() {

}
```

The program works without a destructor but of course has memory leaks, which is unacceptable. When I add a simple destructor such as :

```
if(name){
 delete[] name;
}
```

It will throw that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your copy-ctor you assign the value of name to the new object, so the the dtor will run for both the original and the copied object yet each will try and free the pointer.

In your ctor allocate a new buffer and copy the contents. Even better would be to simply use std::string as the Display member, then the only buffer you would need to concern yourself with is the one you use to query the OS.

Comment: when you say allocate a new buffer an copy the contents what exactly do you mean? c++ is fairly new to me and i'm not sure what a buffer would be. is that another name for a char array?

Comment: I mean in your copy-ctor have: size_t len = strlen(p.name); name = new char[len + 1]; strcpy(name, p.name); Doing that both the copy and original will have different buffers (note there may still be problems because you didn't show what you are passing to the ctor of the original Display object). And like I said, it would be far better to use std::string as the member type.